# Strange complex analysis identity

Tags: complex-analysis

I recently had a homework problem in complex analysis where we had to prove the following identity: Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a disk of radius $R_0$ centered at the origin. Then for $\vert z \vert < R$, where $0 < R < R_0$, we have
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})\textrm{Re}\left(\frac{Re^{i\theta} + z}{Re^{i\theta} - z}\right)d\theta.$$

Does anyone know where this came from/if it has a name/etc.? Also, I'm curious about applications/when this integral can be evaluted/etc. I can't really envision a situation in which this would be useful.

Comment: This is Cauchy's Integral formula. It is one of the most important and fundamental theorems in Complex Analysis. It is used to prove a huge chunk of theorems in complex analysis, from the Maximum modulus principle to Louisville theorem.

Comment: But Cauchy's integral formula, as far as I know, is usually stated as
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w - z}dw.$$
I'm interested in the specific use of the alternate form in the question.

Comment: @PaxKivimae: (pedantry) it's Liouville

Comment: This is the Poisson integral formula. It is actually true for harmonic functions, not just analytic functions, and has many applications (for example, to find solutions for the Laplace equation).

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Poisson integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel). It expresses the values of a harmonic function (in particular: of an analytic function) in the interior of the disk $D_R$ in terms of its values on the boundary $\partial D_R$. For the proof you start with the Cauchy integral formula and apply some symmetry considerations. Note that in the case at hand the function $f$ was analytic in $\bar D_R$ to start with. If the given function is just an arbitrary real function on $\partial D_R$ the integral gives you the (uniquely determined)  *harmonic extension* of $f$ into the interior of $D_R$.